# Remove quotes from Json output

Tags: php, android, json

I need to remove double quotes in my json output, I will exlain more. I obtain this result:

```
[{"id":"1","nom":"Magasin Jardins 2","ville":"Paris","latlng":["36.85715,10.127245"]}
```

I need to remove quotes at the value of latlng I want to obtain that latlng":

```
[36.85715,10.127245]
```

This is my code

```
  $qry = "SELECT *FROM magasin";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);

  //  $promotions = array();
    $response = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   // $promotions[]= $row;
 $magasin = array();
        $magasin["id"] = $row["id"];
        $magasin["nom"] = $row["nom"];
        $magasin["ville"] = $row["ville"];
        $lat = $row[latitude];
        $long = $row[longitude];

       $magasin["latlng"][] =floatval($lat).",".floatval($long);;

// push single product into final response array
        array_push($response, $magasin);
    }
     mysql_close($con);



  echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You don't remove the quotes. You decode that JSON string back to a native data structure, which lets you directly access a particular element's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$magasin["latlng"][] = floatval($lat).",".floatval($long);
```

use

```
$magasin["latlng"] = array(floatval($lat), floatval($long));
```

If on PHP 5.4+ you can instead use

```
    $magasin["latlng"] = [floatval($lat), floatval($long)];
```

This will allow the lat and long values to be passed as floats in the array, instead of typecasting to a string by using the `.",".` to concatenate.